# Booting A Pendrive On Lubuntu for windows

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu

I have recently installed Lubuntu on my acer aspire 4720z and wanted to switch back to windows but the main problem is that i cannot get the iso over the USB by rufus( as it is not recognising my pendrive, i have installed rufus-3.13.exe from the rufus website and ran it from the Lx terminal by the command - wine rufus-3.13.exe but it is not recognizing my USB)

I tried to write my USB via an app ( i think it is disk) but when i start my system and tried to USB boot via the pendrive, it says that there is no operating system. PLZ HELP ME OUT. I am trying to install win 8.1 or 10 or 7 but plz get me out of Lubuntu............PLZZZZZZZZ

Comment: Windows is very picky how their installer USB is made from Lubuntu/Linux.  mkusb or woeusb are about the only two programs that will make a Windows installer work.

Comment: The process you are following to make a bootable Windows Install USB seems uttterly confusing. It does not require Wine. It does not require Rufus. You did not provide a link to whatever instructions you are following, but they don't seem like the instructions from Microsoft. Plzzzzz edit your question so that is is clear and answerable.

Comment: @David  Lubuntu is an official flavour for this site.  Question asking to make Windows USB from Lubuntu.

Comment: @David: First line the OP clearly says it is a Lubuntu question. His use of Wine confirms it is a Linux question. Most importantly, Ubuntu can be used to answer this question

Comment: @user535733 There are 26 answers on that page, many obsolete. Which answer would you recommend the OP start with?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron well, I was thinking of yours, which is the best of those answers.

Comment: Thank you @user535733, but that answer is at the bottom of the list and has no upvotes. Most readers would ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

while I'm not sure if this would works, but might as well give it a try.

1. plug in your USB and run disks.
2. click on "format disk" and choose "MSDOS" in partitioning.
3. click on create a new partition and choose NTFS system.
4. mount window 10 ISO and copy all the files to your USB.

you should able to boot from the USB and install window 10.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing Windows 10 without USB using Ubuntu GRUB

- Backup the Target drive.
- Create a 6GB NTFS partition on the hard drive and extract the Windows ISO to it.
- Create a 20GB, or larger, NTFS partition on the hard drive for the Windows Installation.
- Open Disks, (Gnome-Disks), and note Device, (/dev/sdx), and UUID of the Windows ISO extract partition.
- For msdos partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`*:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda4)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-592C85254E2CD0B7' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  592C85254E2CD0B7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 592C85254E2CD0B7
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

- Edit menuentry, changing `sda4 to sdax`, `msdos4` to `msdosx` (4 places), and 592C85254E2CD0B7 to UUID, (3 places), to suit step 4 above.
- Run `sudo update grub` confirm that `ntldr /bootmgr` appears in grub.cfg.
- Boot the computer into the newly created Windows menuentry and install Windows into it's new partition.
- Reinstall Ubuntu if desired, the GRUB bootloader will have been replaced with the Windows bootloader.

*For gpt partition table, copy the following menuentry to `/etc/grub.d/40-custom/`:

```
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sdc1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-5642BC722509341F' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  5642BC722509341F
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5642BC722509341F
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
    ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

**Boot selecting Windows from the GRUB menu and follow the instructions.**